# Why is my while condition only updating once?

Tags: python, while-loop, return, break

My program works the way I would like it to work except for once it reaches the end and outputs score. I would like it to output the score of correct answers (assuming its out of 10 because it should prompt with 10 questions). However, it never takes into account the first question asked when deducing the score. For example, if I get all ten questions correct, I will only get a 9. It also has an issue when I get the first question incorrect. If I get the first question incorrect and all the other questions correct I get a score of zero. Maybe it has to do with the fact that my while num_of_questions <= 8 loop runs my program ten times whereas I would've thought it would run ten times if i had a ten in the place of the eight?

```
import random

def main():
    ten_questions()

def get_level():
    while True:
        try:
            level_input = int(input("Level: "))
            if level_input in [1,2,3]:
                return level_input
        except:
            pass


def integer_generator(level):
    if level == 1:
        x = random.randint(0,9)
        y = random.randint(0,9)
    elif level == 2:
        x = random.randint(10, 99)
        y = random.randint(10, 99)
    else:
        x = random.randint(100, 999)
        y = random.randint(100, 999)
    return x, y



def question_generator(x, y):
    real_answer = x + y
    wrong_counter = 0
    while True:
        try:
            answer_given =  input(str(x) + " + " + str(y) + " = ")
            if int(answer_given) == real_answer and  wrong_counter == 0:
                    return True
            elif int(answer_given) == real_answer and wrong_counter != 0:
                break
            else:
                while wrong_counter < 2:
                    print("EEE")
                    wrong_counter +=1
                    break
                else:
                    print(str(x) + " + " + str(y) + " = " + str(real_answer))
                    print("False, that was last attempt")
                    break

        except:
            print("EEE")
            pass


def ten_questions():
    num_of_questions = 0
    total_correct_answers = 0
    my_level = get_level()
    correct_answers = question_generator(*integer_generator(my_level))
    while num_of_questions <= 8:
        question_generator(*integer_generator(my_level))
        num_of_questions +=1
        if correct_answers == True:
            total_correct_answers +=1
    print("Score: " + str(total_correct_answers))




if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Before the loop `correct_answers = question_generator(...)`. In the loop `question_generator(...)` You ignore the return from that function.

Comment: I'm surprised by your observed results.  I'd expect it to report you either got them all right, or all wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't read the entire code but in your function **ten_question()** you start **num_of_questions at 0 and exit the while loop when num_of_questions is 9**.

So **your while loop is always running 9 times instead of 10**.

Change the while to:

```
while num_of_questions < 10:
```

or

```
while num_of_questions <= 9:
```